# .sh script is not executed as the user I want therefore scp does not work

Tags: ubuntu, bash, scp, daemon, transmission

I was using the GUI version of Transmission for Ubuntu. 
When my torrents were downloaded I ran the following script as user server with the corresponding ssh keys:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/home/server/Downloads"
find . -type f | while IFS= read filename; do
case "${filename,,*}" in
*.part) : ;; # Excludes *.part files from being moved
*.resume) : ;;
*.torrent) : ;;
*.trashinfo) : ;;
move.sh) : ;;
# Include
*document*) scp "$filename" "imac@imac.local:/users/imac/Documents/" ;;
# Else
 *) echo "Don't know where to put $filename" ;;
esac
done
```

Now I'm using transmission-daemon and the script is not executed as server anymore, therefore, scp does not work because when trying to ssh to imac@imac.local it prompts for a password (no ssh key for that user).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have read access to "server" private ssh key, use the **-i** modifier with scp, that tells it to use a specific private key file.

BTW, isn't shorter to write this?

```
find /home/server/Downloads -type f -iname *document* -exec scp -i pathtokeyfile "{}" "imac@imac.local:/users/imac/Documents/" ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help. The problem is that transmission-daemon is not running the script as root. I logged the user with "echo "$USER" >> $LOG_FILE" and it returns an empty log file. If I run it as server or root it returns the corresponding user.